# In Critical Role campaign 1, did Keyleth ever cast Revivify?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, critical-role

My friend is convinced she remembers Keyleth (moon circle druid) using Revivify at some point. Revivify is *not* a Druid spell, but she swears up an down she remembers Keyleth casting it in Critical Role campaign 1.

***Did Keyleth ever cast the spell revivify during Critical Role campaign 1? If so, when?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Tal'Dorei Campaign Stats](https://www.critrolestats.com/stats-vm) page on CritRoleStats, Keyleth never cast Revivify. On that page under Rankings, there's a link to a spreadsheet of all spells cast during the campaign. Link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y7FB0rEUX8Ik0MfGUtsdItoFWcvlgpGVcSJ0l9-dGDw/edit#gid=524017790). On the Keyleth tab, it lists her as casting the following 3rd level spells (highlighted in green). Revivify (3rd level) isn't on the list. That's not absolute proof of course, but crit role stats is pretty reliable.

[image]